# Finding the location of the country in which it is located, regardless of the device language

Tags: react-native

I want to know which country the device is in. The "react-native-localize" package doesn't work as I want it to. Because if the language of the phone is changed to English on the device in India and Indian is removed, the country code is US. Is there a way I can find out the country where the device is located, regardless of the phone language?

Comment: Geolocation if the phone allows it, or IP address will sometimes work but not always since they can use a VPN

Comment: @DaveS Is there a package you can recommend for this?

Comment: Sorry, no.  You'll need to do your own research on geolocation and geoIP unless someone else comments.

Comment: You can see if there is any libraries in https://www.ip2location.com/development-libraries that you can use for IP geolocation